# displaying data from database into cardview list onclick button

Tags: android

I developed a search function and it worked successfully. The class responsible for the search is called from onQueryTextSubmit and there was nothing wrong with it.

Now I wanted to add other thing that is a button in the same activity of the search bar that when it's clicked all data from the database is displayed in cardView. When I added the code the onQueryTextSubmit method is no longer working plus the button isn't displaying the data. I do not know where is the problem. Here is the code for the whole activity. 
PS: for some reason it says that showdata() method is never used.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find_skill);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewer);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchList);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        noData = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
        noNetwork = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nonetwork);
        urlAdress = "http://skillsexchangecyprus.com/SEC/ss.php";


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getData();
            }
        });


      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(FindSkill.this, urlAdress,listView, query,noData,noNetwork);
                sr.execute();
                return false;
            }
          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
              return false;
          }});}

          private void getData() {
              class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
                  ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                  @Override
                  protected void onPreExecute() {
                      super.onPreExecute();
                      progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FindSkill.this, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
                  }

                  @Override
                  protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
                      super.onPostExecute(res);
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                      parseJSON(res);

                  }

                  @Override
                  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                      BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                      try {
                          URL url = new URL(Config.GET_URL);
                          HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                          bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                          String json;
                          while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                              sb.append(json + "\n");
                          }
                          return sb.toString().trim();
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          return null;
                      }
                  }
              }
              GetData gd = new GetData();
              gd.execute();
          }
    public void showData(){
        adapter = new CardAdapter(Config.skills,Config.ids);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


          private void parseJSON(String json) {
              try {
                  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                  JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

                  config = new Config(array.length());

                  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
                      Config.skills[i] = getSkill(j);
                      Config.ids[i] = getId(j);
                  }

              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

          private String getSkill(JSONObject j){
              String name = null;
              try {
                  name = j.getString(Config.JSON_NAME);
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return name;
          }

          private String getId(JSONObject j){
              String id = null;
              try {
                  id = j.getString(Config.JSON_ID);
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return id;
          }
```

This is the Config class:

```
public class Config {

        public static String[] skills;
        public static String[] ids;


        public static final String GET_URL = "http://skillsexchangecyprus.com/SEC/mainList.php";
        public static final String JSON_ID = "id";
        public static final String JSON_NAME = "skill";
        public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";

        public Config(int i) {
            skills = new String[i];
            ids = new String[i];
        }

        }
```

Card Adapter class:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<ListItem> items;

    public CardAdapter(String[] skills, String[] ids){
        super();
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i<items.size(); i++){
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.setSkill(skills[i]);
            item.setId(ids[i]);
            items.add(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem myAdapter =  items.get(position);
        holder.skillName.setText(myAdapter.getSkill());
        holder.skillId.setText(String.valueOf(myAdapter.getId()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView skillId;
        public TextView skillName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            skillId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.skillId);
            skillName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.skillName);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post full code of your activity?

Comment: This is the whole code for the activity. If you mean other classes just mention which one so I don't post a ot of code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You did't call your `showData()` method. You need to create an instance of `CardAdapter` and set this adapter to your `recyclerView`.

> **Update `OnCreate()` method as below:**

```
    ..............
    ....................
    urlAdress = "http://skillsexchangecyprus.com/SEC/ss.php";

    config = new Config(INITIAL_VALUE);

    // Adapter
    adapter = new CardAdapter(config.skills,config.ids);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getData();
        }
    });
    ....................
    ..............................
```

2. Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update `recyclerView` with new items.

> **Update `parseJson()` method as below:**

```
private void parseJSON(String json) {

  try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
      JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

      config = new Config(array.length());

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
          config.skills[i] = getSkill(j);
          config.ids[i] = getId(j);

          // Update
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

3. In your `CardAdapter` constructor, use `skills.length` instead of `items.size()`

   ```
   public CardAdapter(String[] skills, String[] ids){
       super();
       items = new ArrayList<>();

       for(int i = 0; i < skills.length; i++){
           ListItem item = new ListItem();
           item.setSkill(skills[i]);
           item.setId(ids[i]);
           items.add(item);
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this will work~

Comment: Thank you for your help. Where I have to call show method?

Comment: @Jou: No need to call showData(). I have already added that code portion in parseJson() method.   See >> adapter = new CardAdapter(config.skills,config.ids);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);  Just update your parseJson() method as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: still not working. this error shows: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Can you please post your whole activity with variable declaration and also adapter and config class?

Comment: This url is not for this task, for displaying data after button is clicked the url used is in Config class. this url is for the search function. 
And what is this INITIAL_VALUE?

Comment: INITIAL_VALUE is the initial length of sting array size will be used in Config constructor. You can use INITIAL_VALUE as 0.

Comment: I have found a problem in your CardAdapter constructor. Please see my updated answers POINT 3.